# Tribes' names with את and without?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, names, avot-patriarch-fathers, vayishlach, vayeitzei

1. "וַתַּהַר לֵאָה וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ רְאוּבֵן"
2. "וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן ... וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ שִׁמְעוֹן"
3. "וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן ... עַל־כֵּן קָרָא־שְׁמוֹ לֵוִי"
4. "וַתַּהַר עוֹד וַתֵּלֶד בֵּן ... עַל־כֵּן קָרְאָה שְׁמוֹ יְהוּדָה"
5. "וַתֹּאמֶר רָחֵל ... עַל־כֵּן קָרְאָה שְׁמוֹ דָּן"
6. "וַתֹּאמֶר רָחֵל ... וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ נַפְתָּלִי"
7. "וַתֹּאמֶר לֵאָה בגד ... וַתִּקְרָא **אֶת־שְׁמוֹ** גָּד"
8. "וַתֹּאמֶר לֵאָה ... וַתִּקְרָא **אֶת־שְׁמוֹ** אָשֵׁר"
9. "וַתֹּאמֶר לֵאָה ... וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ יִשָּׂשכָר"
10. "וַתֹּאמֶר לֵאָה ... וַתִּקְרָא **אֶת־שְׁמוֹ** זְבֻלוּן"
11. "וְאַחַר יָלְדָה בַּת וַתִּקְרָא **אֶת־שְׁמָהּ** דִּינָה"
12. "וַתַּהַר וַתֵּלֶד [רחל] ... וַתִּקְרָא **אֶת־שְׁמוֹ** יוֹסֵף...׃"
13. "... וַתִּקְרָא שְׁמוֹ בֶּן־אוֹנִי וְאָבִיו קָרָא־לוֹ בִנְיָמִין"

Why some names are preceded with את and some not?

Comment: Notably, the names preceded with את are the ones borne from Zilpah’s first child until they left Lavan, with the exception of Yissachar.

Comment: Also notably, no shevet that says על כן קראה שמו has את in it, this may hint to something

Answer (score -1):

Sefer Rokeach says that the ones with את added, each had a twin sister. I can not find link to Rokeach, but this link brings the point at the beginning of page 10 https://forum.otzar.org/download/file.php?id=80446&sid=58ea389fe0fe2e79c2504ef5ee8c92a4

Comment: Can you provide an exact reference?

Comment: I don't see (a) any reference to Sefer Rokeach, on page 10 of the document you linked, nor (b) any mention that [only] the ones with את added had a twin sister. If you can't quote (i.e. bring the words of) the Sefer Rokeach itself, at least quote, from the document you linked, the part that says that [only] the ones with את added had a twin sister, and attributes it to Sefer Rokeach.